# earth sciences or Earth sciences

Tags: word-usage

I am writing my personal statement for graduate school. But I saw the word was sometimes "Earth sciences" and sometimes "earth sciences". which one is the formal world if I refer to the certain research field?

Comment: As far as I know, it should be Earth sciences (or Earth science to refer to all the sciences related to the Earth). Please wait for answers from others.

Answer (score 3):

"Earth" is one of those tricky words where there are several situations where different people use different capitalization. There are a few cases where it's cut and dry, however:

- Capitalize "Earth" when it appears in the context of other capitalized celestial bodies. Ex: Mars is about half the size of Earth.
- Do not capitalize "earth" when referring to dirt or soil.

Perhaps others can chime in with other hard and fast rules...

Having said that, I wouldn't say that either "Earth sciences" or "earth sciences" is wrong, since neither rule applies.

You may want to look at the web site for the school where you're applying to see if they prefer capitalizing "Earth" or not. [Stanford's School of Earth Sciences](https://pangea.stanford.edu/about), for example, seems to use "Earth sciences". [University of South Dakota](http://www.usd.edu/arts-and-sciences/earth-sciences/), on the other hand, seems to use "earth sciences".

Note that university departments are usually all capitalized, so you would write Department of Earth Sciences.

Answer (score 0):

Geoscience sounds good and current too. I studied environmental science at a leading env.science university, today that course is named Geoscience.